# Reverse Proxy Nginx Docker Container

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have problems to run multiple proxies and connect a nginx reverse proxy to it.

The image show what I want to archive
[image: This is what I want to archive]

What works is when I connect to a proxy directly

```
# proxy 1
print(requests.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", proxies={
    "http": "127.0.0.1:9000",
    "https": "127.0.0.1:9000"
}).content)

# proxy 2
print(requests.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", proxies={
    "http": "127.0.0.1:9001",
    "https": "127.0.0.1:9001"
}).content)
```

But it did not work when I use the nginx reverse proxy

```
# nginx
print(requests.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", proxies={
    "http": "127.0.0.1:8080",
    "https": "127.0.0.1:8080"
}).content)
```

Response:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request')))
```

That's my docker container yml file

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2.4"
services:

  proxy:
    image: qmcgaw/private-internet-access
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:9000-9001:8888/tcp
    environment:
      - VPNSP=Surfshark
      - OPENVPN_USER=${user}
      - PASSWORD=${pass}
      - HTTPPROXY=ON
    scale: 2

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
        - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

and my nginx configuration

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://proxy:8888;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any advice you can give me.

Comment: Your nginx configuration doesn't seem to be providing a port in the `proxy_pass` statement, so it's going to be connecting on port 80. I think you want `proxy_pass http://proxy:8888`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo, still the same result

Comment: I map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host, thats why im using 127.0.0.1:8080 and that's not a typo, but thanks

Comment: In your second example (using `127.0.0.1:8080`), where exactly is that code running?

Comment: on the host, https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXWKvm.png

Comment: Ignoring Python and Requests, have you verified that you can connect to nginx at `127.0.0.1:8080` using e.g. `curl`?

Comment: So you want a "reverse proxy" or "load balancer" in front of multiple "forward proxies"? https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Qtu.png

Comment: @larsks 'curl 127.0.0.1:8080' returns unsupported scheme.

I think I want a reverse proxy of multiple forward proxies, because the load balancer comes from docker (scale parameter). That's why I am using proxy:8080 and not proxy_1:8080. When the python script is running "inside" of a container, I can use {
    "http": "http://proxy:8888",
    "https": "http://proxy:8888"
} as proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's not what I wanted, but it works with twisted instead of nginx. Maybe someone finds a better solution.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  proxy:
    image: qmcgaw/private-internet-access
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VPNSP=Surfshark
      - OPENVPN_USER=${user}
      - PASSWORD=${pass}
      - HTTPPROXY=ON
    scale: 2

  twisted:
    container_name: twisted
    build: .
    restart:
      always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080/tcp
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl https://google.de --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080"]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM stibbons31/alpine-s6-python3:latest

ENV SRC_IP="0.0.0.0"
ENV SRC_PORT=8080
ENV DST_IP="proxy"
ENV DST_PORT=8888

RUN apk add --no-cache g++ python3-dev

RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install service_identity twisted

WORKDIR /app
ADD ./app /app

CMD [ "twistd", "-y", "main.py", "-n"]
```

**main.py**

```
import os

from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.protocols.portforward import ProxyFactory

SRC_PORT = int(os.environ["SRC_PORT"])
DST_PORT = int(os.environ["DST_PORT"])

application = service.Application("Proxy")
ps = internet.TCPServer(SRC_PORT,
                        ProxyFactory(os.environ["DST_IP"], DST_PORT),
                        50,
                        os.environ["SRC_IP"])
ps.setServiceParent(application)
```